# How do i install bash-git-prompt in Git For Windows bash shell?

Tags: git, git-bash

How would I go about installing bash-git-prompt in Git For Windows bash shell?

Docs at https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt make mention of ~/.bashrc which I don't have. I've found bash.bashrc in /etc and bash_profile.sh in /etc/profile.d which I suspect might be relevant.

Git bash already has its own git-prompt.sh which it uses to somehow provide its own git prompt, I suspect I have to somehow disable or replace this git prompt implementation with the one from https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt, but I have no idea how.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1:

Find where you install Git, then in directory `Git/etc`, clone repo [bash-git-prompt](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt):

`git clone https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt.git`

## Step 2:

Open file `bash.bashrc` (in directory `Git/etc`) using any editor, comment out all the code, add only three lines:

```
GIT_PROMPT_ONLY_IN_REPO=1
GIT_PROMPT_THEME=Evermeet  # you can choose any theme you like, just select one in Git\etc\.bash-git-prompt\themes 
source /etc/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh
```

Save file, reopen your git bash window, Voila! It's all done~

## Problem:

If you find that the symbol in your bash window fails to display, you can solve it by：

`right click on the title bar -> Options -> Text -> Font Select -> DejaVu Sans Mono`

**Ref**：[Strange character](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/63)

> The font limitation shows up in the default Ubuntu shell on Windows 10 as well but I was able to see the glyph characters by simply using DejaVu Mono https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/.
>   What [@scotlynhatt](https://github.com/scotlynhatt) means is [download the font](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/blob/master/DejaVuSansMono/DejaVu%20Sans%20Mono%20for%20Powerline.ttf) on windows, install it and then select it from the font menu for the WSL window (right click on the title bar -> properties -> font).

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own .bashrc

```
touch ~/.bashrc
```

Then go and edit with your favourite editor.